# $q promise not resolving on load, but changing state resolves it

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to resolve a promise from my service to my controller.

**Service.ts**

```
public SetupPromise: angular.IPromise<any> = this.$q.defer().promise;
```

**Controller.ts**

```
//include my Service in my Controller
private Service: Service

this.Service.SetupPromise.then(() => {
    console.log("Promise resolved");
});
```

To resolve my promise, I use do this:

**Service.ts**

```
this.SetupPromise = this.$q.resolve();
```

When doing this, it should resolve the promise inside my controller. It works fine and it does resolve it, but only when I change state and come back to the controller. The whole `SetupPromise.then()` is located inside my constructor of my controller.

**HOWEVER** for some weird reason (perhaps timing?), I can resolve the promise, if I do this inside my controller:

**Controller.ts**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.Service.SetupPromise.then(() => {
        console.log("Promise resolved);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Basically wait a second before doing the promise "setup". What's even more weird, is when I load the page with my controller in it, it loads the promise setup first, then the service afterwards. So it's not because one loads before the other.

Am I resolving my promise wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to say, that I can see the promise being resolved (at least it hits the `then()`, but the stuff inside the `then()` never gets fired initially. Changing state and it will call whatever is inside.

Comment: Could you add jsfiddle or plunker, because from single lines of code difficult to compile it in the brain.

Comment: @Mikki I would love to create a demo for you, but unfortunately I am using an Angular wrapper for SignalR, and I'm sure that won't just run in Plunker :( I'm simply wondering if `this.SetupPromise = this.$q.resolve();` is the best way to resolve a promise, or if something like `this.SetupPromise.resolve();` would work, so the current promise gets resolved, instead of replacing the whole promise with a resolved one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God dammit, I fixed it.. I was wondering why this didn't work properly, and so I tried a few different things (few being like.. all of them). I ended up doing this instead:

Service.ts**

```
public SetupPromise: angular.IDeferred<any> = this.$q.defer();
```

Basically making it deferred at first, but instead of making it a promise, it's just an "deferred promise" (is that right)? After that, I could resolve it like this:

**Service.ts**

```
this.SetupPromise.resolve();
```

Then in my controller I would do this:

**Controller.ts**

```
this.Service.SetupPromise.promise.then(() => {
    console.log("Promise resolved");
});
```

and now it works.. Man that was odd. Obviously I had to resolve the promise, instead of replacing it with a resolved promise.

Comment: Nice one. You forgot double quote at the end of `"Promise resolved`

Comment: @Mikki Whoops haha. It was just example code I made up for this question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here - you are rewriting your promise in this line `this.SetupPromise = this.$q.resolve();`. I will give you TypeScript pattern for using defer object:

**Service.ts**

```
public promise: ng.IPromise<any>;
private defer: ng.IDeferred<any>;

constructor(
    private $q: ng.IQService
) {
    this.defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.promise = this.defer.promise;
    this.defer.resolve();
}
```

**Controller.ts**

```
this.Service.promise.then(() => {
    console.log("Promise resolved");
});
```

In such pattern, you are exporting only promise property, and keep your defer object private.

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's what I ended up doing instead.